# Execute a command daily per user

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-java-edition-server

I want to give a fixed amount of money to users each day they are connected (calendar real life days) to the server. The money is managed by Essentials. I've seen the plugin [OnTime](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/ontime/).

Is this the only way or it can be done with Essentials config or command?

Comment: Do you mean real calendar days or in-game days?

Comment: You could try making a kit for Essentials that gives money that your users can use once every 24 hours (86400 seconds). But then that wouldn't be automated.

Comment: @JayLapham I mean calendar days

Comment: Looking at the plugin, are you trying to reward players based on their playtime? (So if a player plays on your server for a accumulated 24 real hours, that player would be given a reward.) By the looks of it, that plugins seems to be your only solution... I don't think there are others out there that does that.. Well, not that I know of.

Comment: @aytimothy ok, you can add that as an anwer

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it, your only solution is to use the plugin you've found: OnTime, allows automated rewards based on a player's playtime on the server.
In my experience, I haven't heard of any other plugin that does that... Until now.

*Essentials can still be used, but it will not be automated and the user will always have to use the /kit command every time he logs in.*

Remember to install Vault as it is required. And **yes**, Vault can use Essentials' built-in economy system.
Also note that the plugin you've found isn't exactly executing commands (ie. /give [player] 1 50) but instead adding items to players' inventories/money balances.

Comment: As said in comments, this cannot be automated. And also has other problems, like when a user joins the server at 23pm and stays for more than an hour... he should get money two times

Comment: Are you trying to make a daily login reward or add money to users' accounts every [insert a length of time here]?

Comment: Update: Answer in the comments converted (ish) into an actual answer.